# retrieve values from model in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, controller, repository

I don't know how to create functions to retrieve the values.

****Table 1:*** OrgVasplans*

-Id

-vasplanId

-OrgId

-CreatedDate

**Table-2: vasplans**

-Id

-name

-amount

-validity

-vasdurationId

**Table-3: VasDuration**

Id

Duration.

These are my tables..

I have Controller named **Candidatesvas** and action method **VasDetails**....

I already stored the values into **vasPlans** table.

when I click in view "**Details**" link it will go to details page..

Then the values are retrieve from "Orgvasplans" table automatically without enter any input..

How to create methods for this....

I created some methods but the method contains only Name "field". I want to retrieve multiple values like "Amount", "validity" like that.....

**Repository:**

```
    public IQueryable<VasPlan> GetVasPlans()
    {
        return from vasplan in _db.VasPlans
               orderby vasplan.Name ascending
               select vasplan;
    }


  public OrgVasPlan GetOrgVasPlan(int id)
    {
        return _db.OrgVasPlans.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Id == id);
    }

    public int AddOrgVasPlan(OrgVasPlan orgvasplan)
    {
        _db.OrgVasPlans.AddObject(orgvasplan);
        Save();
        return orgvasplan.Id;
    }

    public void AddVasPlan(VasPlan vasPlan)
    {
        _db.VasPlans.AddObject(vasPlan);
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult VasDetails(FormCollection collection)
    {
        OrgVasPlan orgvasplan = new OrgVasPlan();
        orgvasplan.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        orgvasplan.OrgId = LoggedInOrganization.Id;
        orgvasplan.vasplanId=??????????????

        VasPlan vasplan = new VasPlan();
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Name"])) ;

        _repository.AddOrgVasPlan(orgvasplan);
        _repository.Save();            
        return View();
    }
```

Here i don't know how to put code here for get multiple values form vasplans table like(amount,name,validity etc...,)
this is my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make your view strongly-typed, make sure you create input elements whose names correspond to the model properties (or use HTML helpers, e.g. `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount)`. That way MVC will automatically fill in the model for you when the action that should take the model as a argument, is invoked.

For example your action should be:

```
public ActionResult NewVasPlan(VasPlan vplan)
{
    //check model state
    //save or return error messages
}
```

Or you can simply add string and int parameters to the Action like this:

```
public ActionResult NewVasPlan(string name, int amount /*, etc*/)
{
    //MVC will also automatically fill name, amount, from request POST or GET params 
    //(or cookies??)
}
```

Hope this helps, tell me if you need more info or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: actually i want to know,  orderby vasplan.Name ascending//here it orders only the name..not other fields. so i don't know how to create method here...

Comment: Are you talking about a Linq statement?

Comment: orgvasplan.vasplanId=?????????????? is this **the** problem? You either let Entity Framework generate an ID automatically, or assign a value (a random guid maybe). I'm having difficulty understanding what you need though

Comment: i don't know what code put there...If single field means i just assign